# Get Non-Inherited Properties

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to read all of the properties of a given object, reading in only those that are declared on the object's type, excluding those that are inherited.  IE:

```
class Parent {
   public string A { get; set; }
}

class Child : Parent {
   public string B { get; set; }
}
```

And so I want to only get B back.  Reading the docs, I assumed below was what I needed, but that actually returned nothing at all.

```
var names = InstanceOfChild.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly).Select(pi => pi.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks for this question, i was just pulling my hair out over this

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just need a couple other BindingFlags

```
var names = InstanceOfChild.GetType().GetProperties(
   BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
   BindingFlags.Public |  
   BindingFlags.Instance).Select(pi => pi.Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
var names = InstanceOfChild.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly).Select(pi => pi.Name).ToList();
```

I added the `BindingFlags.Instance` and `BindingFlags.Public` to the search parameters, which according to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx) respectively:

> Specifies that instance members are to
> be included in the search.

and

> Specifies that public members are to
> be included in the search.

Comment: it's counter intuitive to me that the Instance flag is required here